# window.onbeforeunload executed on page close instead of refresh in chrome

Tags: javascript

Below code i used for execute file on page refresh or page close.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {

        var a= document.createElement('script');
        a.type = 'text/javascript';
        a.async = true;
        a.src = 'http://192.XXX.X.XXX/clear.js';
        var r = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
        r.parentNode.insertBefore(a, r);
        return 'Are your sure?';

};
```

This working fine on page close but problem with page refresh. This problem occur in Chrome but in Firefox working fine.

I got alert "Are you sure" on page refresh but clear.js not executed on chrome.

Please help!

Comment: what's `return 'Are your sure?';` ??? use `confirm("Are your sure");`

Comment: ok i'll try with `confirm("Are your sure");`

Comment: @vsync In some browsers you can show the returned string in the native dialog, which is shown after `onbeforeunload` has been fired, obviously not in Chrome though.

Comment: @vsync `var confirm("Are your sure"); return confirm;` not working

Comment: `return confirm("Are your sure?");` ... what you just wrote makes zero sense.. how can you return the variable `confirm` if the variable doesn't even exist?

Comment: @vsync you can't prevent the browser from exiting by returning `false`. The only way you can confirm leaving the page is by returning a string in `onbeforeunload`. If you `return false`, no dialog will be shown. You can show a confirm yourself but then you can't prevent the refreshing when the user clicks cancel

Comment: @vsync please look my previous comment where i written my code. i created variable  `confirm` then i call in `return`

Comment: @codemania your syntax is not correct, if you wanted to show a confirm, you would do: `var sure=confirm("Are you sure?");return sure;`, but as I said in my previous comment that won't work

Comment: @codemania - you most certainly did not create any such variable. look again. Or, do you want me to explain to you how javascript works?

Comment: @MaxMeijer - well I didn't know that, but good to know. maybe you can write the OP an answer..

Comment: and BTW, you can just write `document.scripts[0]` instead of that long line `document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]`...

Comment: @vsync and @MaxMeijer now `confirm` return flash

Comment: @codemania Are you sure clear.js doesn't get called. It seems weird that it does work when closing and not when refreshing. Can you create a fiddle

Comment: @MaxMeijer.. i'm sure clear.js doesn't get called.

Comment: did you check your NET panel in your browser's inspector? did you checked the HTML, to see if that script was even included? please provide more information.